# Is there a way to force OpenGL identifiers to start at one instead of zero?

Tags: c++, opengl, coding-style, null, indexing

I store OpenGL identifier in variables of the type `GLuint`. But I do not know to what value I should initialize these variables. I would like to initialize them to zero, but unfortunately that is a valid identifier for OpenGL.

The variables must be initialized before storing the OpenGL objects because that is asynchronously done later. So can I somehow force OpenGL to start indexing with one instead of zero? Or should I use `GLint` and initialize to `-1`?

I would like to solve this in a clean way. Of course I could store a pair of the variable and a boolean flag or something like this. But that would be hacky. How do you approach this issue?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> I would like to initialize them to zero, but unfortunately that is a valid identifier for OpenGL.

No it isn't. [0 means "not an object" for most OpenGL object types](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/OpenGL_Object#Object_zero). The only ones that have a valid 0 object are FBOs (where 0 means [Default Framebuffer](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Default_Framebuffer)), transform feedback objects, and textures (which you should treat *as if* they were not objects).

So just use zero. It's legal to call any `glDelete*` with a zero, and nothing will happen, even if 0 is a valid object for that type.

Answer (score 2):

> Of course I could store a pair of the variable and a boolean flag or something like this. But that would be hacky. How do you approach this issue?

Use `boost::optional`, which is a template based implementation of what you've described. [See here.](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/optional/doc/html/index.html)

With that you can do something like this:

```
boost::optional<GLuint> foo; // Uninitialised
if (foo) // foo evaluates to false
{
    Bar(*foo); // Doesn't execute
} 
*foo = 3; // Initialised
if (foo) // foo evaluates to true
{
    Bar(*foo); // Executes
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out `boost::optional`. In my case there is a more easy solution, but you solved the general issue.